# Maximise the profit, Job scheduling

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, greedy

I have a scenario, in which every timeslot has a profit and muliple jobs to choose from. I need to select the jobs at each time slot such that overall maximum profit is obtained. I require the maximum profit obtained and the schedule.

The only thing I can think of is to try for every comibnation using bruteforce. How can I solve this problem effectively.Is there any way I can do it better by using specific algorithm or data structure?

In the below example , any of the jobs J1,J2,J4 can be selected for timeslot1. Similarly for other time slots any one or none of the jobs can be selected. Only one job can be selected for a particular timeslot. If a job is done in one time slot, it cannot be done again.

Eg. If j1 is done in TS1, it cannot be picked again in TS2

```
+----------+--------+----------------------+
| TimeSlot | Profit | Possible Job         |
+----------+--------+----------------------+
|        1 |     50 | J1 or J2 or J4       |
|        2 |    100 | J1                   |
|        3 |     20 | J2                   |
|        4 |     60 | J5 or J4             |
|        5 |     15 | J1 or J2 or J3 or J6 |
+----------+--------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Can you be more precise with this example ? TS1 => J4, TS2 => J1, TS3 => J2, TS4 => J5, TS5 => J3 or J6 ?

Comment: I think this is linear programming, not dynamic programming. There are many linear programming libraries and optimization libraries, but you haven't tagged a language on this, so I can't suggest you anything

Comment: That being said, there should either be an associated cost with a job or a limit to the number of jobs in a time slot, otherwise the answer is obviously place all jobs in time slot 2 since it yields the most profit

Comment: This is [bipartite graph maximal matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs).

Comment: @criket_007. At any time slot at max only one job can be selected.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Still, though, what is the "cost" associated with picking a job?

Comment: @cricket_007 There is not cost associated with each job. When I select a Job1 in TS1 , the profit will be +50 (But J1 cannot be done in TS 2 becaues JS is already done.). I need to do jobs in such a way that the profit is maximum

Comment: If there is no negative cost with a job and the only disadvantage to assigning a job once is that it is "locked" to that time slot, the answer is jobs (4,2,1,5,6 or 3) with either job 6 or 3 "unemployed" depending on which is assigned.

Comment: @cricket_007 I got it, but how can I solve it using an algorithm(In case for very large input). How can I be sure that , I select the correct job at each time slot.

Comment: Programmatically, I only know how to do it with python since that's how I was taught in school and it's been years since learning that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved optimally by [weighted maximum matching in bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs).

In here, your graph is `G=(U,V,E)`, where:

```
U = {1, 2, ...., n} // time slots
V = {J1, J2, ..., J_m} // jobs
E = { (i,J) | if job J can be done in time i }
w(i,J) = profit(i)
```

A maxmum matching in the above graph is translated directly to an optimal solution, by performing task `J` in timeslot `i` iff the maximum matching matched node `J` with node `i`.

Comment: Thanks. I never thought that this problem can be modelled using a graph. Also are there any other ways I can solve this,even though its not as efficient as maximum maching?

Answer (score 0):

public class JobProfitMaximizer {

```
private int numberOfJobs;
private Job[] jobs;
private int maxProfit;

public class JobComparator implements Comparator<Job> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Job arg0, Job arg1) {
        if (arg0.end <= arg1.end)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}

public JobProfitMaximizer() {
    numberOfJobs = 0;
    maxProfit = 0;
}

private void printJobProfiles() {
    for (Job j : jobs) {
        System.out.println(j.start + " " + j.end + " " + j.profit);
    }
}

private void createJobProfiles() {
    jobs = new Job[numberOfJobs];
    File inputFile = new File("***Filepath***********");
    Scanner sc = null;
    int jobCounter = 0;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            String[] profileOfJob = s.split(" ");
            int start = Integer.parseInt(profileOfJob[1]);
            int end = Integer.parseInt(profileOfJob[2]);
            int profit = Integer.parseInt(profileOfJob[3]);
            jobs[jobCounter] = new Job(start, end, profit);
            jobCounter = jobCounter + 1;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("The file is not present");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (sc != null)
                sc.close();
        } catch (Exception f) {
            System.out.println(f.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void setNumberOfJobs() {
    File inputFile = new File("***Filepath***********");
    Scanner sc = null;
    int countOfJobs = 0;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            countOfJobs = countOfJobs + 1;
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        numberOfJobs = countOfJobs;
        System.out.println(numberOfJobs);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("The file is not present");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (sc != null)
                sc.close();
        } catch (Exception f) {
            System.out.println(f.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void sortJobsOnFinishTimes() {
    JobComparator jc = new JobComparator();
    Arrays.sort(jobs, jc);
}

private void calculateMaximumProfit() {
    int[] T = new int[numberOfJobs];
    T[0] = jobs[0].profit;

    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfJobs; i++) {
        T[i] = Math.max(T[i - 1], jobs[i].profit);
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (jobs[j].end <= jobs[i].start) {
                T[i] = Math.max(T[i], T[j] + jobs[i].profit);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int currentMaxProfitValue = T[0];

    for (int m : T) {
        if (m > currentMaxProfitValue) {
            currentMaxProfitValue = m;
        }
    }
    maxProfit = currentMaxProfitValue;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JobProfitMaximizer j = new JobProfitMaximizer();
    j.setNumberOfJobs();
    j.createJobProfiles();
    j.sortJobsOnFinishTimes();
    j.calculateMaximumProfit();
    System.out.println("The maximum profit is " + j.maxProfit);
}
```

}

Comment: Maintain an array T[] for storing the maximum profit and keep updating it. Sort the jobs on their finish times. After sorting the jobs, if 2 jobs Job(i) and Job(j) do not overlap then set T[i] = max(T[i],T[j] + profit[j]). Finally, choose the maximum among T[] which will be the final maximized profit value.

Comment: This is bottom up dynamic programming since the recursion unwinds